# sinon- assert args on function with stubs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

How can I assert on the args of this function with stubs?

```
  templatesResource.one = function(arg) {
    if (arg == 'apple'){
      get: sinon.stub().returns getTemplatesDeferred.promise
    } else {
      get: sinon.stub().returns getTemplatesDeferred.promise
   }
  }
```

---

```
expect(templatesResource.one).to.have.been.calledWith(123)
```

Comment: You can try making templatesResource.one = sinon.stub that returns an object with another get stub - then use stub.args[0][0] to assert the first arg of the first call

Comment: ya....tried that...got undefined when it called `get()`

Comment: then it is likely that the first stub of templatesResource.one is not returning the proper thing - are you able to post that code as well?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, hope it helps others:

```
  templatesResource.one.withArgs('default_types')
    .returns(get: sinon.stub().returns getTemplatesDeferred.promise)

  templatesResource.one.withArgs(123)
    .returns(get: sinon.stub().returns getTemplateDeferred.promise)
```